# Using condition to set OPTION in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

Is there a way to set an OPTION statement based on a condition? The code below is being executed in a stored procedure. The select statement is just a sample. The option placement has to come after the WHERE statement, but I get an error using the IF statement after the WHERE.

I need something like this:

```
declare @time int = datepart(hh, getdate())

select * 
from my_table 
where x = something

if (@time > 8)  
 OPTION (LABEL = 'day')  
else
 OPTION (LABEL = 'night')  
end
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is not ANSI/ISO SQL.)

Comment: MS SQL Server 2016

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically have two options.  Either repeat the SQL:

declare @time int = datepart(hh, getdate());

```
if @time > 8
    select *
    from my_table 
    where x = something
    OPTION (LABEL = 'day')  ;
else
    select *
    from my_table 
    where x = something
    OPTION (LABEL = 'night')  ;
```

Or use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = '
    select *
    from my_table 
    where x = something
    option (label = ''[label]'')
';

set @sql = replace(@sql, '[label]', case when @time > 8 then 'day' else 'night' end);

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

Comment: Is there a downside to using dynamic SQL. I see a lot of comments complaining about dynamic SQL.

Comment: @John . . . It means that it is parsed on each execution.  It is harder to maintain.  The database doesn't store dependency information in certain metadata tables.  However, duplicating the code also presents maintenance problems.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answer. I accepted it as the answer because it seems like the only viable option, although I did not end up using it directly. My stored procedure is called from a VB.net script. So I check the time of day with that and then call the appropriate stored procedure in SQL (which is basically a copy with the OPTION set the way I need it in each one).